# Variable type to hold different type of methods(multi signature)

Tags: c#, vb.net, methods, delegates, c#-2.0

I'm using vb.net 2.0. I know delegates can be used for holding different function of same signature. What type i can use for methods of multiple signature?

My case is like this. I need to create a list of items and its corresponding operations(Methods). The signature of opertaion may different for each. This list will get passed as a parameter to another function. That function should be able to execute the operations(methods) with each item in the list. To hold the methods which type variable is best

Thanks and Regards
Binesh nambiar C

Comment: Sounds like what you want is an overloaded method

Answer (score 0):

The base Delegate type can be used for your list instead of specific delegate types. Invocation is a bit complicated: use reflection to get the compiler-generated Invoke() method for the delegate type, which you can then call via the MethodInfo object for it. And of course you'll need some mechanism for providing the varying argument lists.

Another option is to push the generalization back on to the caller. Make your API store a list of Action, and require the caller to provide a suitable delegate instance that accepts the object[] of arguments for the invocation, and invokes the appropriate strongly-typed delegate instance itself.

For example:

```
List<Action<object[]>> _delegateList;

void Target(string arg1, int arg2) { ... }

void Caller()
{
    AddDelegate(args => Target((string)args[0], (int)args[1]));
}

void AddDelegate(Action<object[]> callback)
{
    _delegateList.Add(callback);
}
```

And then later:

```
void InvokeDelegate(int i, object[] args)
{
    _delegateList[i](args);
}
```

It's not clear from your post how you will correlate a delegate in this list with the arguments that need to be passed to it, so I kind of glossed over that above. Presumably you have some reasonable mechanism in mind.

If you know the argument list at the time that the delegate is being added to the list, then of course you don't need an Action as your delegate list type. It can just be Action and you can capture the argument values in your initial lambda expression in the "Caller()" method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this: why not call the method an let the compiler's overload resolution algorithm figure it out?

Anyhow as a fun little excercise (I am bored today) you could build something similar to the following (having `dynamic` I'm not sure there is a scenario where it could be useful):

```
public class OverloadDelegateList
{
    readonly object target;
    readonly string methodName;
    List<InvokableMethod> methods;

    public OverloadDelegateList(Delegate firstOverload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(firstOverload != null);

        this.methods = new List<InvokableMethod>();
        this.target = firstOverload.Target;
        this.methodName = firstOverload.Method.Name;
        AddOverload(firstOverload);
    }

    public IEnumerable<InvokableMethod> InvokableMethods
    {
        get { return this.methods; }
    }

    public void AddOverload(Delegate d)
    {
        Debug.Assert(d != null);

        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(d.Target, target))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        if (d.Method.Name != this.methodName)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        this.methods.Add(new InvokableMethod(d, (from p in d.Method.GetParameters() select p.ParameterType).ToArray()));
    }

    public object DynamicInvoke(params object[] args)
    {
        var signature = new MethodSignature((from a in args select a.GetType()).ToArray());
        var overload = this.methods.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Signature.Equals(signature));

        if (overload == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return overload.InvokableOverload.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class InvokableMethod
{
    readonly MethodSignature signature;
    readonly Delegate invokableMethod;

    public InvokableMethod(Delegate invokableMethod, params Type[] types)
        :this(invokableMethod, new MethodSignature(types))
    {
    }

    public InvokableMethod(Delegate invokableMethod, MethodSignature signature)
    {
        Debug.Assert(invokableMethod != null);

        this.invokableMethod = invokableMethod;
        this.signature =signature;
    }

    public Delegate InvokableOverload { get { return this.invokableMethod; } }
    public MethodSignature Signature { get { return this.signature; } }
}
```

---

```
public class MethodSignature: IEquatable<MethodSignature>
{
    readonly List<Type> signature;

    public MethodSignature(params Type[] types)
    {
        this.signature = types.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> Signature { get { return this.signature; } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as MethodSignature);
    }

    public bool Equals(MethodSignature other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        if (other.signature.Count != this.signature.Count)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.signature.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (this.signature[i] != other.signature[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 0;

            if (this.signature != null)
            {
                foreach (var t in this.signature)
                {
                    hash ^= t.GetHashCode();
                }
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use this as follows:

Consider the following class `Foo` implementing 5 different overloads for method `Bar`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("Bar() called: {0}", string.Empty); }
    public void Bar(int i) { Console.WriteLine("Bar(int) called: {0}", i); }
    public void Bar(double d) { Console.WriteLine("Bar(double) called: {0:N4}", d); }
    public void Bar(int i, string s) { Console.WriteLine("Bar(int, string) called: {0} & {1}", i, s); }
    public void Bar(double d, string s) { Console.WriteLine("Bar(double, string) called: {0:N4}, {1}", d, s); }
}
```

You could build up a list containing all information of `Foo.Bar()` overloads like so:

```
 var foo = new Foo();
 var overloads = new OverloadDelegateList(new Action(foo.Bar));
 overloads.AddOverload(new Action<int>(foo.Bar));
 overloads.AddOverload(new Action<double>(foo.Bar));
 overloads.AddOverload(new Action<int, string>(foo.Bar));
 overloads.AddOverload(new Action<double, string>(foo.Bar));
```

And now you can dynamically invoke the correct overload based on the *runtime* number and type of the arguments:

```
//We want to call Bar overload with one argument.
object arg1 = 1d;
overloads.DynamicInvoke(arg1);

//We want to call Bar overload with two arguments.
object arg2 = "s";
overloads.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2);
```

Note that for this solution to work you need to have *static* knowledge of `foo` (callee).  If you have no static knowledge of the callee then you will need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173183(v=vs.110).aspx) to figure out the possible overloads too.

Comment: Why i need it is because the calling of the function will be after lots of operation which will be dynamically(may multiple times) after deciding which operation need to happen.